# Symfony 3.4 CollectionType Edit Form

Tags: forms, symfony, loops, symfony-3.4

I got a form that include eight CollectionType, as simpleArray.

I should made a page that edit the entity and render a table with form inputs.

That's what I've made

```
{% for items in form.floor.vars.value %}
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.floor, ['data',form.floor.vars.value[i]]) }}
    </td>
    <td>
        {{ form_widget(form.ambient, ['placeholder', form.ambient.vars.value[i]]) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:270px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:150px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.pp, ['data', form.pp.vars.value[i]]) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:150px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.pl) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:150px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.pt) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:150px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.c1v) }}
    </td>
    <td style="min-width:150px;">
        {{ form_widget(form.c2v) }}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This render a single `<td>` with all of the form inputs inside, I should render a  `<td>` block for each one item inside the array ( the values in entity got the format `1,4,2,6,8,4`, each one got the same number of values so I'm using the first item that got the values in the for loop.

Other problem I got is that the `ambient` field is a dropdown (CollectionType with an EntityType inside), i've tried to pass the value as `data` or as `placeholder` but i got no data, just the first item in list given by EntityType.

```
$expertations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Expertations::class)->find($id);
[..]
 ->add('ambient', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => EntityType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:Rooms',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                        ->orderBy('u.name')->distinct()
                        ;},
                'label' => false,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => 'id',
            ],
            'label' => false,
            'attr' => ['class' => ''],

        ])
[..]
```

Ask me If I missing something.